# overlay with pseudo :before also darkens text that should remain white

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an element with a background image and some text in it.
For various good reasons the element is positioned `absolute`.

I added an overlay to the image with a pseudo `:before`.

The problem now is that the overlay also darkens the text in the element.
How would I fix that? I want my text to remain nicely white!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xvdk95st/

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.gyazo.com/1e88fee290bda821ba823a76a1e01c04.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.text::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Hi, I'm some text!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `z-index` with `position` on `<p>` (because `z-index` always works with `position`), like:

```
.text p {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.gyazo.com/1e88fee290bda821ba823a76a1e01c04.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.text::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 2;
}

.text p {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Hi, I'm some text!
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to darken background only, you can use multiple backgrounds:

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
    url('https://i.gyazo.com/1e88fee290bda821ba823a76a1e01c04.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Hi, I'm some text!
  </p>
</div>
```